# Is it possible to have different desktop sessions each with different settings?

Tags: gnome, themes, session

In this situation, I have a default Ubuntu session with the Paper and Materia Theme, and a Communitheme session. The problem is, I want the default Ubuntu session to use the themes I chose for it, and the Communitheme session to use Communitheme.

The theme settings stay on whatever I left it on when I switch (for example, I log out of the default session and switch to Communitheme, but the themes from the default session are still active and I have to manually switch to Communitheme using Gnome Tweaks.)

Is there a way I can have the two different sessions use different settings, or have it switch themes automatically?

Comment: @Ramuyko That actually works enough for me, would you mind putting that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different users can keep different theme configurations. You can create and remove users on the terminal with `sudo adduser mynewusername` and `sudo deluser mynewusername`. This way you'll be able to switch between sessions with completely different configurations.

When you create new users they can't use the `sudo` command by default. If you wish to give the new user access to `sudo` for installing and removing software from the system you need to add `mynewusername` to the `sudo group`. You can do it with the following command:

```
sudo addgroup mynewusername sudo
```