# Run two gnome sessions simultaneously on a single desktop, isolating one from another

Tags: xorg, gnome-shell, gdm, session, guest-session

This is to expand on [Is it possible to have different desktop sessions each with different settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043114)

First off I know how to run two desktops by running something like `xinit /usr/bin/xfce4-session -- :2`. This is not a problem, I can do that. I am trying to run specifically two *gnome3* sessions. The issue I encounter is that second gnome session will not execute, even when I sudo to a different user. I can execute another type of session, such as xfce4 in given example, but not gnome.

Another thing I'm noticing is that some windows in the second session are popping up on 1st display. For example, when I click on an encrypted directory, the password prompt pops up in first session.

So I guess what I'm looking for is how do I:

- run multiple user sessions,
- each one on its own display,
- switch between them at will using Ctrl+Alt+Fn,
- separate them from each other so that one don't open windows on another

Please don't offer workspaces as a solution. I want to ensure separate sessions are used, separate users are running them, and when something happens in one (like click on URL) it is isolated from another session

Comment: Using multiple *workspaces* properly is much easier than hacking to achieve multiple *sessions*.

Comment: not really @user535733 . workspaces will not isolate apps. For example, if I click on the URL on one workspace, it can open it in browser in another one. This is what I use now and this is what I want to NOT use

Comment: You can simply go to the GDM screen with Ctrl+Alt+F1 (?) and then login with a second user. Then you have exactly what you want and you can switch with Ctrl+Alt+Fn.

Comment: That worked! wow, why didn't I think of it myself. Wanna copy/paste it into an answer, and I'll close the question?

Comment: @pLumo - wanna copy your answer to proper answer instead of comment?